# Laravel Breeze (vue) and Homestead - npm run dev and HMR not working

Tags: laravel, breeze, homestead, hot-reload

I followed the instructions from the documentation:

1. Homestead: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/homestead#installation-and-setup
2. Breeze with Vue and inertia: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia

When I run `npm run build` everything works fine. I can visit my new app over http://homestead.test/. When I try to use the dev server with hot reload `npm run dev`, the debug console in my browser (host) tells:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I already tried to change my *package.json* file to from `"dev": "vite",` to `"dev": "vite  --host homestead.test",` but this only results in the errors

```
GET http://homestead.test:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://homestead.test:5173/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

In *app.blade.php* the scripts are imported with @

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

`@routes` seems to be a part of the Laravel Ziggy package. No error from this side.

But the `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` and `@inertiaHead` are throwing errors. These directives link to a wrong destination.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. Add the server part in your *vite.config.js*. And add the app.css to the inputs

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
          host: "192.168.56.56",
        },
        host: "192.168.56.56",
        watch: {
          usePolling: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'], 
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you!
additionally I had to add the "alias" to fix console warning.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is to turn on the HTTPS with Vite SSL cert generation plugin

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        https: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        basicSsl(),
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share a little of my experience when I get a problem like this. This is because the existing IP is not detected on the device.

[image]

http://127.0.0.1:5173 that's the route that made this error occur. So I tried building with

```
npm run build
```

after that I refreshed my page and the page was successfully opened.

[image]

looks like it was not accessible during development stage. that's all I understand. sorry if there is an error that I convey.