Laravel: CSS not Rendering When Using Vite for Asset Compilation
I am encountering an issue with my Laravel project where TailwindCSS styles are not being rendered when using Vite for asset compilation. Here's the simplified project structure:
app/
bootstrap/
config/
database/
node_modules/
...
public/build/assets/app-DkC-8ICp.css
public/build/manifest.json
...
resources/css/app.css
resources/js
resources/views/welcome.blade.php
...

In my /resources/welcome.blade.php file, I have the following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Campus Brainshare</title>
    <!-- TailwindCSS -->
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <h1 class="text-red-500 font-bold">Hello, Stack Overflow!</h1>
</body>

</html>


When I run php artisan serve, only the HTML code is being rendered, and the CSS styles are not applied. Additionally, when I manually link to the CSS file using <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('/public/build/assets/app-DkC-8ICp.css')}}">, I receive a "Mixed Content" error in the browser:
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.


Moreover, when I run command for both php artisan serve and npm run dev together then CSS works as expected.
I want to know why the CSS is not rendering when using Vite for asset compilation and how to resolve this issue?

Is this localhost? production with HTTPS? The error message Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS should be your clue here. Your app is running behind HTTPS but your assets are on HTTP or vice versa.

Did you add the your app-DkC-8ICp.css in the vite config? See here

@Mr.Kenneth Mixed error from production server.

Are you using Apache/Nginx? Did you already set the SSL/HTTPS in your server(Let's encrypt, etc)?

Try this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74462960/13933721

I have solved the problem by simply  adding a production .env variable ASSET_URL=the https production url of my app.

Always write the version in Laravel questions.
Write down everything you did "from project creation".
In Laravel, what you do after creating the project is important.
If you create a project with the Breeze/blade stack in Laravel 11, no strange errors will occur.
There is no need to do anything unnecessary like <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('/public/build/assets/app-DkC-8ICp.css')}}">.
Do not change @vite().
You only need to use the build command.
npm run build


Your suggestion is very basic. It's already done. Not working.
